# Upgrading existing Wordpress 4.1 to 4.6. What are some obstacles I might encounter?

Tags: upgrade

I have a 4.1 wordpress and I need to update it to the latest, which is 4.6 currently. Have there been common or known issues during an upgrade like this? Also I am new to wordpress upgrading as I am mainly a Drupal dev. In drupal I would just download the newest version and just move all the files into my existing version and then do a database update. How is this done in wordpress from 4.1 to 4.6?

What is a step by step approach to this upgrade?

Comment: Besides some plugins or themes that may not fully compatible with a new version, for most WP websites the process is smooth and easy. Backup your db just in case, hit the Update button and check the site. If it's all good, back and frontend, you dont need to do anything else. Some plugins/themes may have not been tested for the latest version but work perfectly fine. In case of issues, you'll have to debug.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is way too broad to answer thoroughly. By far the most common type of issue is a theme/plugin that is incompatible with the new WP version. So you want to check that first.

The upgrade from 4.5 to 4.6, for instance, brought more thorough error catching, prompting plugins to stumble over errors that previously went unnoticed.

After checking the compatibility status of your plugins it's just a matter of backing up your database and pushing the 'update' button.

UPDATE Depending on how critical your site is, you could also clone it and update/debug the cloned install first, before moving on to the live server.